# In C, what is the expected behavior of passing a struct as an argument to printf?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, code-generation

## Second try

Ok, maybe my first attempt to ask the question was too confuse. So, here we go again...

In a function that takes a variable number of arguments, like `printf`, when you pass a struct what is the kind of code generated you should expected?

I'm asking this, based on this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct edge{
    int v1, v2;
};

int main(void){
    struct edge edges;

    edges.v1=5;
    edges.v2=20;

    printf("'%d'\n",  edges);

return 0;
}
```

When compiling this on my windows box, it pass 2 integer arguments:

```
    .file   "simple_test_case2.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "'%d'\12\0"
    .text
.globl _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $5, 24(%esp)
    movl    $20, 28(%esp)
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

But the code generated by my linux box, just pass one memory address to it:

```
    .file   "simple_test_case2.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "'%d'\n"
    .text
    .align 2
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
.LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI1:
    subq    $16, %rsp
.LCFI2:
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $20, -12(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
.LFE2:
    .size   main, .-main
.globl __gxx_personality_v0
    .section    .eh_frame,"a",@progbits
.Lframe1:
    .long   .LECIE1-.LSCIE1
.LSCIE1:
    .long   0x0
    .byte   0x1
    .string "zPR"
    .uleb128 0x1
    .sleb128 -8
    .byte   0x10
    .uleb128 0x6
    .byte   0x3
    .long   __gxx_personality_v0
    .byte   0x3
    .byte   0xc
    .uleb128 0x7
    .uleb128 0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .uleb128 0x1
    .align 8
.LECIE1:
.LSFDE1:
    .long   .LEFDE1-.LASFDE1
.LASFDE1:
    .long   .LASFDE1-.Lframe1
    .long   .LFB2
    .long   .LFE2-.LFB2
    .uleb128 0x0
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI0-.LFB2
    .byte   0xe
    .uleb128 0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .uleb128 0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LCFI1-.LCFI0
    .byte   0xd
    .uleb128 0x6
    .align 8
.LEFDE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

So this is my question, when you pass only one struct to a function like `printf`, the code generated should pass just one argument or push all struct members to it?

## First try

A friend of mine was having some problems with a program that wasn't working as expected on Windows. So I took a look at the source code and trimmed down the test case to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct edge{
    int v1, v2;
};

int main(void){
    struct edge edges;

    edges.v1=5;
    edges.v2=20;

    //This is the expected behavior for me:
    printf("'%d' '%d' '%d' '%d'\n",  edges.v1,  edges.v1,  edges.v1,  edges.v1);

    //This is supposed to work like this? It should pass the whole struct to printf?
    printf("'%d' '%d' '%d' '%d'\n",  edges,  edges,  edges,  edges);
    printf("'%d' '%d' '%d' '%d'\n",  edges,  edges);

    return 0;
}
```

So tested on a Windows 7 box with

```
gcc (tdm-1) 4.5.0
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And the output is this:

```
'5' '5' '5' '5'
'5' '20' '5' '20'
'5' '20' '5' '20'
```

On a linux box with

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I got this output:

```
'5' '5' '5' '5'
'5' '5' '5' '5'
'5' '5' '229971840' '-641776368'
```

The output from linux box one, is the one that i expected...

Then, I took a look at the assembly code generated by each compiler and saw that on my Windows box, the code was passing the whole struct to printf, both v1 and v2 members (and this justifies the results). But on the Linux box, the code generated passed just the first member of the struct, as I expected.

So what should be the behavior in this case?

For me, the expected one is the Linux one, but maybe I'm wrong and this is a case of undefined behavior.

Comment: I would expect the Windows behavior, but I suspect the behavior is actually undefined because it's a stdarg function.

Comment: The Linux and Windows versions agree on the `printf` call that isn't UB. Why do you care what the other two `printf` calls do? You'd never write code like that would you?

Comment: If your format string contains four `%d` then the next four parameters to `printf` _must_ be `int`. Anything else invokes undefined behavior so you shouldn't really expect any specific behavior.

Comment: @David: Misread.  Sorry, deleted :)

Comment: @Buss How were you able to predict the output of the values 229971840 and -641776368? I'm impressed that you could do that.

Comment: @Buss:  I don't "hope" anything.  C isn't Java or whatever; if you don't pass a `struct` pointer, it passes the entire actual `struct`, as shown by the Windows version. I *think* what's happening with Linux is that `gcc` handles `printf` specially (`__attribute__ ((printftype))`), but `struct` handling isn't implemented by `printftype` so you're getting a default behavior (treat as `(int)`, I suspect).

Comment: @yi_H clearly the linux code is pushing two ints and then stopping

Comment: @David Heffernan: I expected that those 2 last numbers, would be memory garbage. And no... it's not a production code, it's just a simple test code that i built as a example of a much more complex one, just to illustrate the case.

Comment: yeah but didn't know why until I read to last comment (thx @geekosaur)

Comment: Ok... i will try to be more clear.

I know printf, C and what i should pass or not. My problem here is that on the (asm) code generated on Windows box, it's passing a total of 8 arguments to printf, it's not passing 4 struct address or anything like that... it's passing 8 integers to printf and this is what i don't understand why.

You want me to put asm code on the question?

Comment: @Buss What you do is undefined behavior. You should not expect anything about the code that's generated. The compiler could just produce code that does not make sense. (you're also viewing 32 bit vs 64 bit assembly, which is certainly going to impact the code generated, as there's certainly a big difference in calling convention on windows 32 bit vs linux 64 bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the compiler doesn't have specific information about how the argument should be passed, such as when there's no prototype or for arguments that are passed where the protoype have an ellipsis (`'...'`), the compiler follows certain rules for passing the arguments:

- the integer promotions are applied (note this doesn't apply to structures)
- if the argument has `float` type it's promoted to double

After these default argument promotions are applied, the argument is simply copied to wherever the compiler normally copies arguments (generally, the stack). So a struct argument would be copied to the stack.

Try examining the assembly output for the following code, and you'll see that GCC will copy the structures passed to `foo()` to the stack:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo( size_t siz, ...);

struct x
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct y
{
    char a;
};

struct z
{
    double x;
    double y;
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    struct x x1;
    struct y y1;
    struct z z1;

    foo( sizeof(x1), x1);
    foo( sizeof(y1), y1);
    foo( sizeof(z1), z1);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC might not be applying this rule to your `printf()` test because it has special knowledge of `printf()` and knows that only certain types are supported by the format string.  If an argument type doesn't match what's expected by a format specifier then undefined behavior occurs (so the compiler doesn't have to do what you might expect otherwise).  I'm surprised you don't get some sort of warning.  If you leave out the `#include <stddio.h>`, you'll probably see a warning something like, "warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'", which hints at GCC's special treatment of `printf()`.

Answer (score 8):

The expected behavior is **undefined behavior**. The C language requires that you pass arguments of the correct type (matching the format string) to `printf`, and there is no format string which can match `struct` types.

You may be able to get the C implementation you're using to print meaningful data by passing structures this way, but it's non-portable, dependent upon calling convention, and unreliable.  Don't do it. Just pass the individual members you want to print.

Answer (score 2):

Look, `printf` is just a simple function.
It evaluates its arguments from right-to-left and just pushes them on the stack.
It does *no* type checking.

Then the format string expects to see certain things, namely ints, doubles, or character pointers.
Nothing else.

So just pass it what it expects.

Comment: @Mike: The wording in his question is confusing, but it *seems* like he expects it to throw up when passing the whole struct. @Buss: Is this correct?

Comment: @Buss: If you pass a struct, it looks like on Windows it copied the struct onto the stack. On Linux I'm not sure what it did. In both cases, it's relying on you to pass the right thing, and that doesn't include structs.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to type-check anything.

The question is, if it should pass the whole struct (as on my windows box) or just the first member (as on my linux box).

On the assembly generated in the windows box, it's passing 8 arguments to second printf (4 times the both members of struct)... and i really can't see this as expected.

Comment: @Buss printf is expecting integers because you said `%d`. Mike's last line is the only sane advice.

Comment: @Buss: What is expected is that you will not pass a struct to `printf` (or any `vararg` function, I believe). If you do, it will not work right.

Comment: @Buss, when you use %d as a specifier, you pass it an int. When you use %s, you pass it a pointer to a sequence of char's that end in a nul byte. When you use %u you pass it an unsigned int. The printf documentation covers all the other format characters. That's what you have to read, and you have to pass in something of the correct type according to the format specifier.

Comment: @Buss: Suppose your first format is `%d`, and your first argument is a double `3.5`. What do you think it prints? It quite happily prints garbage, because it takes the low-order 32-bits of the double and assumes it's an `int` and prints it. It's relying on you to pass ints, doubles, or char* in the order needed by the format, and if you don't, it will happily chew through the arguments as if you had.

Comment: @Mike: actually, a `struct` passed by value should be fine, but knowing that that part of the `va_arg` is a `struct` is something you need to work out for yourself and code accordingly, and if the function isn't expecting a `struct` then the result is undefined. It's just painful and fragile enough that nobody does it. (Fragile in that the programmer gets no warning if they didn't follow whatever protocol you defined to recognize them.)

Comment: Ok... i will try to be more clear.

I know printf, C and what i should pass or not. My problem here is that on the (asm) code generated on Windows box, it's passing a total of 8 arguments to printf, it's not passing 4 struct address or anything like that... it's passing 8 integers to printf and this is what i don't understand why.

You want me to put asm code on the question?

Comment: @Buss: It sounds like you are really asking - what does the compiler generate if I pass a struct to a `vararg` function. Since the compiler has no idea if it's legal to do that, it just does something. It doesn't really matter what, because it's undefined. It hopes that whoever wrote the function will know what to do with it.

Comment: So, i think this is a better way to state the question:

In a vararg function, if you pass a single struct it should pass what? A single argument? Or N arguments, where N is the number of struct arguments?

Comment: @Buss: The keyword is "should". Since you know you shouldn't do that, it has no spec to follow if you do. I wouldn't require different compilers to do the same thing, or do anything at all, really. Maybe what it should do is generate a warning message saying "Don't Do That!"

Comment: So i can never pass a struct to a vararg function? If i create a vararg function myself, that receive a variable number of structs... i can't do this?

Comment: @Buss you certainly can pass structs to var-arg functions. Just not printf, it is precicely documented what you can pass to printf, and none of the arguments takes structs (and if you pass one anyway, it's anyones guess what'll happen). printf certainly has no knowledge of the structs _you_ have created (and unlike many other languages, C have no run-time introspection capabilities)